# Different behaviors when getting spreadsheet from script properties and from string

Tags: google-apps-script

Lets say I have a main Spreadsheet with some code that writes in a secondary spreadsheet. To get the main and secondary spreadsheets in gas we have to use the basic following code:

```
var ss_main = SpreadsheetApp.openById("fake_id_main_8889D4");
var ss_secondary = SpreadsheetApp.openById("fake_id_secondary_1A2Z");
```

When I want to duplicate the full system, (Main + Code + Secondary), I have to edit the previous code everywhere it occurs to set the new id of the freshly copied secondary spreadsheet.
In order to avoid this, I tried to use the script properties: in the gas framework, in the menu File > Script Properties, I set, for all duplicate systems the two properties id_main_spreadsheet and id_secondary_spreadsheet with their id:

[image: Script properties]

In the code, instead of the previous line, I write this to get the spreadsheets:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

var id_ss_main      = scriptProperties.getProperty('id_main_spreadsheet');
var id_ss_secondary = scriptProperties.getProperty('id_secondary_spreadsheet');

var ss_main     = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_main  );
var ss_secondary= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_secondary);
```

With this process, when I want to duplicate the system I don't even have to edit the code at all, I only have to set the script properties. BUT. There is my problem: at some point in my unitary tests code, I write in a cell in the main spreadsheet, the cell just below gets some value with a formula, I read this new value to test if it is the expected value. It's something like this:

```
ss_main.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(10);
// lets say the following cell in getRange(2,1) as the formula "=A1*2"
var test_value = ss_main.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
// then I test if I found what I expected, the 10*2=20, and I write the result
// into the secondary spreadsheet 
var result = (test_value==20) ? "OK" : "ERROR";
ss_secondary.getSheetByName("Result").getRange(1,1).setValue(result);
```

But with this new code, when I debug step by step, when I run the setValue(10), there is some delay before it is effective in the spreadsheet, and when I go on with the code and read the second cell, the new value is not made yet (since the first cell is not edited yet with the delay), so the test fails, and then only a few line later (randomly), the setValue() is effective and the second cell changes with the good value 20, but it's too late for the test in the code...

When instead of the last code I put the following one with the classic getActive() instead, I still have the delay when I debug step by step but even if the setValue() is not made on my screen, it must be done on the server because I don't encounter the problem anymore, and the test is successfull and moreover, I don't have any problem at all with the secondary spreadsheet still returned with from the script properties!

```
var ss_main = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var id_ss_secondary = scriptProperties.getProperty('id_secondary_spreadsheet');    
var ss_secondary= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_ss_secondary);
```

Does anyone understand why the openByID function and the getActive() function returns me spreadsheet with different behavior (both works but not in the same way!!)?

Comment: Have you tried using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after your `.setValue(10)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have a look at Apps Script [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) documentation.**

It will tell you to minimize calls to other services, because calling those services (even services located on Google Servers - this includes also Properties Service) will make your script slower.

If you feel like you must store your SpreadsheetId in the script properties - make sure that after every line of your code where the PropertiesService is called, you use the [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) method to wait for the call to finish before the rest of the code is run.